# Search entire document with one input mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I want to be able to use one input ( a string or number) to search all fields in a document using Node and mongo (mongoose).
I have a schema that looks like this:

```
const exampleSchema = new Schema({
  sampleId: Number,
  name: String,
  note: String,
});
```

And my controller looks like this:

```
searchExampleRequest = async (req: ExampleDtoSearchRequest, res: Response) => {
  const exampleDtoSearch:ExampleDtoSearch =req.body;
  const respData = await searchExample(exampleDtoSearch);

  res.json(respData);
};
```

Currently, my service only searches the sampleID.

```
const searchExample = async (exampleDtoSearch: ExampleDtoSearch) => {
  return exampleModel.find({sampleId: exampleDtoSearch.sampleId}).exec();
}
```

How do I make it search all the fields

Comment: What is your logic inside `searchExample` function body?

Comment: I edited this with the service